# javascript if statement error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an extensive form. What I am trying to do is compare the numbers in two fields. But I want my code to only use a field if the drop down (carOp8) value is "Simplex". I tried the code several ways and get different results.

carOp8 being the val for the dropdown simOpn1 is just equal to 0.

If I try the code this way:

```
if (carOp8 ="Simplex") {
    var opn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
    if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
        var simOpn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
}}
```

The code works, I get the largest number of the two fields, but the  if (carOp8 =="Simplex") statement doesn't seem to work, so even if the drop down is on something besides simplex, it still runs that code. If the drop down doesn't equal simplex I just want it to skip to the next one. I checked the values for the drop down, spelling, sentex, everything seems fine and the drop downs values are associated with other fields that all work just fine.

If I try it this way:

```
 if (carOp8 =="Simplex") {
        var opn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
        if (Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) {
            var simOpn1 = $("#field_open8").val();
    }}
```

Then it always returns 0 (simOpn1) no matter what the numbers in those fields are, and what option the drop down is on.

I also tried:

```
var opn1 = $("#field_open3").val();
    if ((Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)) && (carOp3 =="Simplex")) {
    var simOpn1 = $("#field_open3").val();
}
```

I get the same result as the previous one.

Comment: How do you expect `Number(opn1) >= Number(simOpn1)` to make any sense if you assign a value to simOpn1 *after* making that check?

Comment: Consider `parseFloat(x)`/`+x` or `parseInt(x)`/`x&0` depending on need - not `Number(..)`, which is fairly non-idiomatic and easily confusible with `new Number(..)`.

Comment: In the first block of code, you have `if (carOp8 ="Simplex")` (with a single `=` instead of `==`). Is that a typo?

Comment: Ted has the answer (the conditional block will always execute and set carOp8 = "Simplex")

Comment: @TedHopp I tried it that way just to see what would happen

Comment: @Bart I assigned it before the check. I give it 0 to start with, but what I want to do is replace it with var opn1 if its larger.

Comment: Also no need to select the value again you can just do `var simOpn1 = opn1`

Comment: @user3724233 If Ted Hopp's suggestion didn't fix the entire problem, I think we'll need more code. Why are you writing `var simOpn1 = ...` if simOpn1 is already declared?

Answer (score 0):

if (carOp8 = "Simplex") will always evaluate to true, so you'll always get into the condition, which is probably not the case with if (carOp8 == "Simplex").

Try checking the value of carOp8 and whether the condition actually evaluates to true at any point...

Comment: It does for my hide/show options. This is the only place where I am having this issue.

Comment: Can you try and debug the code or log carOp8 to console to see what's the actual value. The code with the single equal is exactly as writing if(true), which just skips the first condition.

Comment: I did, the option values are like this Simplex Simpex 1 Simplex 2 simplex 3 Simplex 4 Group 1 Group 2 Group 3..